# NSolve erroneously gives no solution to a polynomial system

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have a polynomial system with three equations in three unknowns, the maximum degree is 26. Two equations are symmetric, i.e. `eq1(x,y,z)=eq2(y,x,z)`. If I search for a symmetric solution with `y=x`, NSolve returns a number of solutions. However, if I apply NSolve to the original system, `{}` is returned after a while, without any errors. What could be going on here?

**Edit:** below are the polynomials in question.

```
eq1 = -400 z^2 (12500 y^3 z^5 (90 (-1+z) z+y (-130-1967 z+1701 z^2))+x^6 (25+420 z+164 z^2) (100 z^2+20 y z (10+189 z)+y^2 (100+3780 z+3321 z^2))^2+6250 x y^2 z^4 (180 (-1+z) z^2+4 y z (-350-3655 z+3213 z^2)+y^2 (-1300-35800 z-148177 z^2+120285 z^3))+5000 x^2 y^2 z^3 (60 z^2 (-25-200 z+126 z^2)+2 y z (-2375-54375 z-242440 z^2+176112 z^3)+y^2 (-3250-129775 z-1201160 z^2-2076368 z^3+1507086 z^4))+2 x^5 (25+420 z+164 z^2) (-10000 z^4-8000 y z^3 (5+92 z)+300 y^2 z^2 (-275-8545 z-45294 z^2+492 z^3)+20 y^3 z (-4250-188475 z-2030715 z^2-57492 z^3+278964 z^4)+y^4 (-32500-1942000 z-27773325 z^2-13103595 z^3+14755203 z^4+4901796 z^5))+500 x^3 y z^2 (-400 z^3 (10+89 z)+60 y z^2 (-525-10795 z-41594 z^2+11076 z^3)+4 y^2 z (-15000-535375 z-5230875 z^2-10618835 z^3+6404076 z^4)+y^3 (-32500-1699500 z-24450075 z^2-98053445 z^3-5080482 z^4+31443228 z^5))+25 x^4 z (-2000 z^4 (10+89 z)-800 y z^3 (200+4460 z+17477 z^2)+120 y^2 z^2 (-4500-153900 z-1409110 z^2-2323793 z^3+82656 z^4)+8 y^3 z (-90625-4401875 z-66277500 z^2-300577200 z^3-20833965 z^4+47108016 z^5)+y^4 (-325000-20987500 z-408812500 z^2-2528313000 z^3-1459453050 z^4+653500107 z^5+366000768 z^6)))
eq2 = -400 z^2 (10000 y^4 z^4 (-5 z (10+89 z)-2 y (25+420 z+164 z^2)+y^2 (25+420 z+164 z^2))+4000 x y^3 z^3 (-50 z^2 (10+89 z)-5 y z (200+4460 z+17477 z^2)-4 y^2 (125+4400 z+39460 z^2+15088 z^3)+y^3 (250+8925 z+81020 z^2+30996 z^3))+600 x^2 y z^2 (1875 (-1+z) z^4+500 y z^3 (-25-200 z+126 z^2)+50 y^2 z^2 (-525-10795 z-41594 z^2+11076 z^3)+5 y^3 z (-4500-153900 z-1409110 z^2-2323793 z^3+82656 z^4)+y^5 (2500+136500 z+2227025 z^2+11086740 z^3+4087044 z^4)+y^4 (-6875-329125 z-4766350 z^2-20412560 z^3-7221576 z^4+80688 z^5))+40 x^3 z (28125 (-1+z) z^5+625 y z^4 (-350-3655 z+3213 z^2)+250 y^2 z^3 (-2375-54375 z-242440 z^2+176112 z^3)+50 y^3 z^2 (-15000-535375 z-5230875 z^2-10618835 z^3+6404076 z^4)+5 y^4 z (-90625-4401875 z-66277500 z^2-300577200 z^3-20833965 z^4+47108016 z^5)+y^6 (25000+1837500 z+42668750 z^2+338995125 z^3+386232300 z^4+102937716 z^5)+y^5 (-106250-6496875 z-130624375 z^2-885247500 z^3-350209800 z^4+107736192 z^5+45750096 z^6))+x^4 (12500 z^5 (-130-1967 z+1701 z^2)+y^6 (25+420 z+164 z^2) (100+3780 z+3321 z^2)^2+6250 y z^4 (-1300-35800 z-148177 z^2+120285 z^3)+5000 y^2 z^3 (-3250-129775 z-1201160 z^2-2076368 z^3+1507086 z^4)+500 y^3 z^2 (-32500-1699500 z-24450075 z^2-98053445 z^3-5080482 z^4+31443228 z^5)+25 y^4 z (-325000-20987500 z-408812500 z^2-2528313000 z^3-1459453050 z^4+653500107 z^5+366000768 z^6)+2 y^5 (-812500-62200000 z-1515303125 z^2-12310874375 z^3-9689455125 z^4+4170740580 z^5+4478607612 z^6+803894544 z^7)))
eq3 = -400 (12500000 (-1+y) y^6 z^8 (25 z+2 y^2 (105+82 z)+5 y (5+84 z))+5000000 x (-1+y) y^5 z^7 (250 z^2+75 y z (10+147 z)+25 y^2 (20+693 z+4652 z^2)+y^3 (4200+60610 z+44772 z^2))+4 x^9 (105+82 z) (2500 z^4+500 y z^3 (20+273 z)+25 y^2 z^2 (600+16380 z+67481 z^2)+10 y^3 z (1000+40950 z+337405 z^2+201474 z^3)+y^4 (2500+136500 z+1687025 z^2+2014740 z^3+544644 z^4))^2+62500 x^2 y^4 z^5 (625 z^4 (-74+9 z)+500 y z^3 (-470-5607 z+378 z^2)+50 y^2 z^2 (-7550-193325 z-1082282 z^2+33228 z^3)+8 y^5 z (147000+4127900 z+25870635 z^2+17756198 z^3)+20 y^3 z (-10250-434275 z-5137625 z^2-16185017 z^3+61992 z^4)+y^4 (-16250-1576375 z-30283800 z^2-106933140 z^3+234123840 z^4+242064 z^5))+12500 x^3 y^3 z^4 (6250 z^5 (-50+9 z)+625 y z^4 (-3610-40630 z+6237 z^2)+500 y^2 z^3 (-11800-278675 z-1440017 z^2+168174 z^3)+50 y^3 z^2 (-135750-5012550 z-54425905 z^2-161386282 z^3+12110364 z^4)+8 y^6 z (1470000+61344500 z+729108450 z^2+2509338345 z^3+1543671402 z^4)+10 y^4 z (-323750-16777875 z-284394650 z^2-1725057270 z^3-2682939630 z^4+44504352 z^5)+y^5 (-406250-30198750 z-718189875 z^2-5601198800 z^3-5235243980 z^4+21387326112 z^5+86416848 z^6))+3125 x^4 y^2 z^3 (12500 z^6 (-74+9 z)+2500 y z^5 (-3610-40630 z+6237 z^2)+125 y^2 z^4 (-269600-6271800 z-31535234 z^2+4879809 z^3)+100 y^3 z^3 (-610500-22016600 z-231267240 z^2-676924767 z^3+95566338 z^4)+10 y^4 z^2 (-5582500-277080750 z-4514172950 z^2-27429959045 z^3-47636823957 z^4+5572844748 z^5)+4 y^7 z (14700000+814100000 z+14268765000 z^2+89719815000 z^3+175946555925 z^4+89184527498 z^5)+10 y^5 z (-2362500-151852500 z-3404834250 z^2-31477458950 z^3-107192270485 z^4-70258903867 z^5+4014973872 z^6)+y^6 (-3250000-266250000 z-7734616250 z^2-91274467875 z^3-353314512600 z^4+81822358510 z^5+682796135744 z^6+7739512272 z^7))+500 x^5 y z^2 (-2500000 z^7+62500 y z^6 (-470-5607 z+378 z^2)+12500 y^2 z^5 (-11800-278675 z-1440017 z^2+168174 z^3)+625 y^3 z^4 (-610500-22016600 z-231267240 z^2-676924767 z^3+95566338 z^4)+500 y^4 z^3 (-1077500-53309750 z-859760550 z^2-5217504375 z^3-9155373012 z^4+1373964516 z^5)+50 y^5 z^2 (-8225000-525798750 z-11613295500 z^2-108006433425 z^3-394956201355 z^4-373424805542 z^5+57710474136 z^6)+4 y^8 z (73500000+5073775000 z+117600525000 z^2+1077107192500 z^3+3626828197125 z^4+3688382662340 z^5+1139229494676 z^6)+10 y^6 z (-15375000-1227393750 z-34936781250 z^2-440165818750 z^3-2389380496125 z^4-4259671880765 z^5-543757517062 z^6+199369046880 z^7)+y^7 (-20312500-2011500000 z-71374225000 z^2-1119790209375 z^3-7315791538750 z^4-12681549935250 z^5+12305201074940 z^6+11922339291856 z^7+378251627040 z^8))+50 x^6 z (-6250000 z^8-2500000 y z^7 (30+431 z)+62500 y^2 z^6 (-7550-193325 z-1082282 z^2+33228 z^3)+12500 y^3 z^5 (-135750-5012550 z-54425905 z^2-161386282 z^3+12110364 z^4)+625 y^4 z^4 (-5582500-277080750 z-4514172950 z^2-27429959045 z^3-47636823957 z^4+5572844748 z^5)+500 y^5 z^3 (-8225000-525798750 z-11613295500 z^2-108006433425 z^3-394956201355 z^4-373424805542 z^5+57710474136 z^6)+50 y^6 z^2 (-53875000-4317337500 z-122350656250 z^2-1545553044375 z^3-8658001464750 z^4-17447002625280 z^5-4281527765016 z^6+1116768103056 z^7)+4 y^9 z (367500000+30385250000 z+876127612500 z^2+10549119450000 z^3+50543244451875 z^4+77207282058450 z^5+46560234887460 z^6+9670806703512 z^7)+50 y^7 z (-17562500-1748150000 z-61641381250 z^2-992616036250 z^3-7418598629625 z^4-21656294896665 z^5-10779809973576 z^6+837951801292 z^7+633852330048 z^8)+y^8 (-101562500-12916093750 z-561037093750 z^2-11032005028125 z^3-98895162378125 z^4-320995927116250 z^5+11541934933200 z^6+321942723499160 z^7+136511538445872 z^8+5502013053120 z^9))+x^8 (12500000 z^8 (-185+256 z)+5000000 y z^7 (-3700-43285 z+71528 z^2)+4 y^9 (105+82 z) (2500+136500 z+1687025 z^2+2014740 z^3+544644 z^4)^2+62500 y^2 z^5 (-16250-1576375 z-30283800 z^2-106933140 z^3+234123840 z^4+242064 z^5)+12500 y^3 z^4 (-406250-30198750 z-718189875 z^2-5601198800 z^3-5235243980 z^4+21387326112 z^5+86416848 z^6)+y^8 (25+420 z+164 z^2)^2 (-29225000-1286281250 z-16042309375 z^2+8122707000 z^3+54598605300 z^4+30273492096 z^5+803894544 z^6)+3125 y^4 z^3 (-3250000-266250000 z-7734616250 z^2-91274467875 z^3-353314512600 z^4+81822358510 z^5+682796135744 z^6+7739512272 z^7)+500 y^5 z^2 (-20312500-2011500000 z-71374225000 z^2-1119790209375 z^3-7315791538750 z^4-12681549935250 z^5+12305201074940 z^6+11922339291856 z^7+378251627040 z^8)+50 y^6 z (-101562500-12916093750 z-561037093750 z^2-11032005028125 z^3-98895162378125 z^4-320995927116250 z^5+11541934933200 z^6+321942723499160 z^7+136511538445872 z^8+5502013053120 z^9)+10 y^7 (-101562500-19520312500 z-1065143281250 z^2-25668581968750 z^3-289577442890625 z^4-1286535678011875 z^5-471989907683000 z^6+1653988149325800 z^7+1479996563635440 z^8+361065214964880 z^9+13535440402176 z^10))+10 x^7 (-6250000 z^8 (5+79 z)-12500000 y z^7 (20+663 z+4211 z^2)+125000 y^2 z^6 (-10250-434275 z-5137625 z^2-16185017 z^3+61992 z^4)+12500 y^3 z^5 (-323750-16777875 z-284394650 z^2-1725057270 z^3-2682939630 z^4+44504352 z^5)+3125 y^4 z^4 (-2362500-151852500 z-3404834250 z^2-31477458950 z^3-107192270485 z^4-70258903867 z^5+4014973872 z^6)+500 y^5 z^3 (-15375000-1227393750 z-34936781250 z^2-440165818750 z^3-2389380496125 z^4-4259671880765 z^5-543757517062 z^6+199369046880 z^7)+250 y^6 z^2 (-17562500-1748150000 z-61641381250 z^2-992616036250 z^3-7418598629625 z^4-21656294896665 z^5-10779809973576 z^6+837951801292 z^7+633852330048 z^8)+8 y^9 z (262500000+25286875000 z+872210062500 z^2+13019934956250 z^3+81022758665625 z^4+165148040303000 z^5+147358962336600 z^6+59875852069440 z^7+8997991630992 z^8)+20 y^7 z (-60156250-7708359375 z-334196875000 z^2-6638447356250 z^3-62930398093750 z^4-245935395612250 z^5-188063456267100 z^6+5474243584200 z^7+28342274761872 z^8+4103157149568 z^9)+y^8 (-101562500-19520312500 z-1065143281250 z^2-25668581968750 z^3-289577442890625 z^4-1286535678011875 z^5-471989907683000 z^6+1653988149325800 z^7+1479996563635440 z^8+361065214964880 z^9+13535440402176 z^10)))
```

**Edit 2:** As is noted in the comments, the system above is huge, and it takes too long to try different solution methods. Interestingly, while working on the initial problem, I came across a much simpler system, but with the same NSolve issue. Here are the equations:

```
foc = {-x^4 y^2+2 x^3 y^3+x^2 y^4-2 x^4 y z+4 x^3 y^2 z-x^4 y^2 z+10 x^2 y^3 z-2 x^3 y^3 z+4 x y^4 z-x^2 y^4 z-2 x^4 z^2+8 x^2 y^2 z^2+8 x y^3 z^2+2 y^4 z^2,x^4 y^4+2 x^3 y^5-x^2 y^6+8 x^4 y^3 z+18 x^3 y^4 z-2 x^4 y^4 z+4 x^2 y^5 z-4 x^3 y^5 z-2 x y^6 z-2 x^2 y^6 z+16 x^4 y^2 z^2+44 x^3 y^3 z^2-4 x^4 y^3 z^2+28 x^2 y^4 z^2-10 x^3 y^4 z^2-8 x^2 y^5 z^2-2 y^6 z^2-2 x y^6 z^2+12 x^4 y z^3+40 x^3 y^2 z^3-2 x^4 y^2 z^3+38 x^2 y^3 z^3-6 x^3 y^3 z^3+8 x y^4 z^3-7 x^2 y^4 z^3-2 y^5 z^3-4 x y^5 z^3-y^6 z^3+3 x^4 z^4+12 x^3 y z^4+14 x^2 y^2 z^4+4 x y^3 z^4-y^4 z^4,y (2 x^2 y^3+8 x^2 y^2 z+4 x y^3 z+10 x^2 y z^2+10 x y^2 z^2-2 x^2 y^2 z^2+y^3 z^2-x y^3 z^2+4 x^2 z^3+6 x y z^3-4 x^2 y z^3+2 y^2 z^3-4 x y^2 z^3-2 x^2 z^4-3 x y z^4-y^2 z^4)}
```

Please note that these are not symmetric anymore. `NSolve[foc,Reals]` gives `{}` without any errors. So does `NSolve[Join[foc, {x >= 1, y >= 1, z >= 1}], Reals]` (the constraints give the domain I am interested in). Running `GroebnerBasis` before `NSolve` still produces no results but the following error message appears from NSolve:

```
Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1.
Returning intersection of solutions with
(171802 x)/178835-(113492 y)/178835-(121484 z)/178835 == 1.
```

The best part of it, the solution exists as can be easily seen from the following contour plot (and by playing with the upper limits it seems the solution is unique):

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@Thread@(foc == 0), {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 1, 10}]
```

`Solve`, given the constraints on the domain, can find that unique solution. Somehow, `NSolve` fails in this case...

**Edit 3:** belisarius has pointed out that `foc/.{x->0,y->0} = {0,0,0}`. It is also the case that `foc/.{x->0,z->0} = {0,0,0}` and `foc/.{y->0,z->0} = {0,0,0}`. I cannot trivially delete these roots from the original equations, because the original equations do not factor so. However, these roots do seem to present the problem when using `NSolve` after `GroebnerBasis` as is evident from the error message. So, I've tried dropping all the small common factors from the Groebner basis.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[foc,{x,y,z}];
NSolve[FactorList[#][[-1,1]]&/@gb,Reals]
```

gives the set of the remaining solutions, with the one I was looking for being among them.

So, it seems that `NSolve` gets caught in the positive dimensionality part of the solution, even if explicitly told the region `(x>1,y>1,z>1)`, where that positive dimensionality is not present. When run after `GroebnerBasis`, `NSolve` at least admits it, but when run on the original equations, it seems to hide the fact.

(I accept belisarius' answer as the comment below helped me to at least have an idea of what might be going wrong.)

**Edit 4:** Just for fun:

```
addConstraints[foc_] := {Sequence @@ foc, x >= 1, y >= 1, z >= 1}
Reduce[addConstraints@Thread[foc == 0], {x, y, z}, Backsubstitution -> True] // N // Timing
{6.87911, x == 6.18083 && y == 4.58414 && z == 3.14352}

gb := GroebnerBasis[foc, {x, y, z}];
NSolve[addConstraints[FactorList[#][[-1, 1]] & /@ gb], Reals] // Timing
{2.97643, {{x -> 6.18083, y -> 4.58414, z -> 3.14352}}}

Solve[addConstraints@Thread[foc == 0]] // N // Timing
{6.84882, {{x -> 6.18083, y -> 4.58414, z -> 3.14352}}}
```

Comment: Since you are looking for a numeric solution, FindRoot is sometimes more aggressive. See if it can find a solution to the original system.

Comment: Can you maybe include the polynomials you speak of in your post?

Comment: @J.M. I've added the polynomials.

Comment: They're huge... and the coefficients are also huge. If you don't mind, could you explain where these came from? At the moment, I can suggest that you try `GroebnerBasis[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {x, y, z}]` and feed the output of that to `NSolve[]`

Comment: @Bill I am interested in real x,y,z so that x > 1, y > 1, z > 1. I know of one solution and what I want is to check whether that's the only one. While I can start FindRoot at random points (and I will do that) and see where it converges, I thought NSolve might be a more robust approach given it should find all solutions. But apparently something goes amiss.

Comment: Did you try adding the constraints you speak of into `NSolve[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Economics... I am looking for a Nash equilibrium of a specific problem. I can easily find at least one equilibrium, but given that my problem has best responses whose derivatives are polynomials, I thought using NSolve on the FOCs would be a neat way to check if the solution I find is the only one. Regarding putting the constraints into NSolve - no I didn't try. Thank you for the suggestion. Trying now (but it probably will take a few hours, so results will be known later).

Comment: Well, your polynomials are huge. :) So, do the two things: (attempt to) simplify your system a bit with `GroebnerBasis[]`, and then feed the output along with your constraints to `NSolve[]`.

Comment: @J.M. It turns out I had an error in my computations, the polynomials I need are slightly different. Also, when I use NSolve to find the symmetric solution, the precision of the result is quite poor, maybe that's the core of the problem somehow. Anyways, I'll try `GroebnerBasis` followed by `NSolve` on the original equations and will let you know what comes out.

Comment: @J.M. `GroebnerBasis[]` is still running, which makes it more than 10 hours. I will stop it now, but in my view this is still a better outcome: I know the problem is too large to solve instead of getting an empty set for a solution from NSolve[].

Comment: Ah. Well, `NSolve[]` uses `GroebnerBasis[]` under the hood, so at the very least, you know now why a solution might take very long to obtain. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Version 10 may be using a polyhedral homotopy method, and running into numeric difficulties in tracking solutions.

Comment: As for preprocessing with `GroebnerBasis`, it would make sense to try at high but finite precision. Not that I had any luck (it eventually gave up at 1000 digits; I've not yet tried higher than that).

Comment: Oh, one other thing. Two of the polynomials factor, and have a common factor of `z^2`. Which means there will be a dimensional component. If that is of use, just pick a value of `x`, set `z` to 0, and solve the last polynomial for `y`. If instead you want to avoid that component, get rid of those factors.

Comment: To illustrate the comment of @bill: `soln = FindRoot[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {x, 2}, {y, 2}, {z, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]; {eq1, eq2, eq3} /. soln`...

Comment: You can get rid of the {0,0} (dimensional component) solutions by adding a variable `r` and a polynomial `x*y*z*r-1`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I find it a excellent suggestion. Unfortunately, `NSolve[Join[foc, {x y z r - 1}], Reals]` still gives no results.

Comment: I got a result quickly with this: `soln = NSolve[Join[foc, {x*y*z*r - 1}], {r, x, y, z}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 200];`. There were 22 solutions, but I don't recall offhand how many were real valued.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, it works. There are 6 real solutions, out of which one satisfies x>1,y>1,z>1. Surprisingly, if I add the constraints to NSolve, it finds no results. I am now trying with `WorkingPrecision -> 200` but it's taking rather long time. Will probably post the results tomorrow.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, your suggestion also works with constraints (x>1,y>1,z>1) or with a domain restriction (Reals), but you need to specify a high working precision. With the default precision this approach does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to deal with the singularities (that lead to dimensional components of the solution space) when `x`, `y` and/or `z` are zero is through a change of variables that lets excessive zeros be factored out.

```
changevar = {y -> x s, z -> x s t};
Short /@ Factor[foc /. changevar]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can use [`FactorList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html) to get at the irreducible factors and delete constants and simple variables.  We find six real solutions, only one of which has all variables positive.  (It was not clear to me whether the lower bound of `1` on the solutions was imposed to try to get rid of the zeros or was part of the system.)

```
nfoc = Flatten@ DeleteCases[
    FactorList[#][[All, 1]] & /@ (foc /. changevar),
    _?NumericQ | s | x | t,
    {2}];
nsol = NSolve[nfoc == {0, 0, 0}, {x, s, t}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 25];
sol = Thread[{x, y, z} -> #] & /@ ({x, y, z} /. changevar /. nsol)
(*
  {{x ->  20.6512,   y ->  1.14137,  z -> -0.452436},
   {x -> -18.1434,   y -> 28.1209,   z -> -6.50644},
   {x ->   6.18083,  y ->  4.58414,  z ->  3.14352},
   {x ->   1.82148,  y -> -4.7767,   z -> -1.25265},
   {x ->   0.885016, y ->  1.62512,  z -> -0.298749},
   {x ->  -1.20071,  y -> -0.747601, z ->  1.57008}}
*)
```

Verify:

```
foc /. sol
(* 
  {{0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-20}, {0.*10^-14, 0.*10^-11, 0.*10^-15},
   {0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-16, 0.*10^-18}, {0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-20},
   {0.*10^-23, 0.*10^-22, 0.*10^-23}, {-0.*10^-22, 0.*10^-21, 0.*10^-22}}
*)
```

Comment: This is also the fastest solution. Removing the factors from the Groebner Basis and then using NSolve takes about 3 sec (was the fastest solution so far). This solution takes about 0.6 sec.

Comment: While this solution works for this particular instance of the problem, it is not general. E.g., `changevar = {y -> z s, x -> z s t}` does not solve the issue anymore, because it misses the hyperplane where `y = 0, x = 0, z > 0`. For the same reason, the extension of this approach to 4 or more equations can be challenging. Whereas removing simple factors from the Groebner Basis and then running NSolve should always do the trick, I guess.

Comment: @Andrei I recall checking something like that for this particular system.  What happens if you fold in the plane and axis and solve each system?  Something like `{y -> 0, x -> z t}` and `{y -> 0, x -> 0}`, and call `NSolve` on each.  That's three calls total to `NSolve`, but each subsequent one is simpler.  But if the way you suggest works, maybe it's simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Too much fuss :)

```
rf1 = Reduce[And @@ Thread[foc == 0] && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, 
             Quartics -> True, Backsubstitution -> True];

Show[ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@Thread[foc == 0], {x, 1, 7}, {y, 1, 6}, {z, 1, 6},
                  Mesh -> None], 
     Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[{x, y, z}, .3] /. (ToRules@rf1 // N)}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
rf1 // N
(* x == 6.18083 && y == 4.58414 && z == 3.14352 *)
```

Comment: The whole problem seems caused by `foc /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}`  being `{0,0,0}`

Comment: It's a good point that `reduce` can find the solution. Albeit, that does not answer the original question of why NSolve cannot. Also, `Quartics->True` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Andrei Usually questions like `Why MyFun[ ] can't do ... whatever` are not answerable. Mathematica inner code and algorithms are (mostly) a black box.